# 画面遷移がかなり重いです。このような場合、原因を特定するのに有効なツールなどはありますか？

Tags: swift

NavigationControllerで、テーブルのセルをタップした時の画面遷移に2秒とかかかります。
アプリを起動したあとの初めての遷移が重いです。

CoreDataを使っていることと何か関係があるでしょうか？

このような場合、原因を特定するのに有効なツールなどはありますか？

Comment: App Storeに並んでいるアプリにはCoreDataを使っていてもサクサクと動いているものがたくさんあります。単に「画面遷移に2秒とかかかります」「初めての遷移が重い」だけでは全く判断の根拠にできるような情報とは言えません。まずは、Time Profiler等を使って情報を集め(「Time Profiler 使い方」あたりで検索すれば、たくさん参考になる記事が出てきます)、それらの情報や関連するご自身のコードを質問に記載してください。

Comment: @LePered'OO コメントありがとうございます。コードのどこを抜き出して質問したらいいのかも分からないレベルです。Time Profiler調べてみます。

Comment: Time Profilerで解決しました！遷移先のTableViewCellに貼っていたtextFieldのフォントがsystemFontでなく特殊なものに設定されていました。これをsystemFontにすることで解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決できてよかったです。今回のあなたのご経験をshareしていただくことは、他の開発者にとっても大変有用だと思うので、お時間を取って「質問」自体を改善(例えば質問部分を「このような場合、原因を特定するのに有効なツールなどはありますか？」なんてのはありではないかと思います)した上で、あなた自身がどう「Time Profilerで解決」したのかを「回答」として記載していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 承知しました。修正してみます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time Profilerを使ってみると、遷移先のビューコントローラーの

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

が重いということが分かり、`tableViewCell`の設定を変えたりなどいろいろ試して、
その部分に関係するところのどこが重いのかをさらに調べたところ、

遷移先の`tableViewCell`に貼っていた`textField`のフォントがsystemFontでなく特殊なものに設定されていることが原因とわかりました。これをsystemFontにすることで解決しました。

Comment: ご質問の修正と回答の投稿ありがとうございます。ご自分の回答を「承認」するのには少し時間をおかないといけないかもしれませんが、是非、解決に至った回答であることを「承認」で示すようにしてください。